# Clicking sound when trying to use electronics in my car

Tags: battery, alternator, starter, electronics

I own Toyota Avensis 2001 D4D 2.0 estate.

Here is the problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ury2rt9wct6dasz/2014-08-18%2017.25.46.mp4

When I am trying to start it - it wont even turn the starter, nothing happens except lights on dashboard go nuts and I can constantly hear clicking sounds. Non of the electronics work - my high beams don't work (just more clicking sound, but no lights), radio doesn't work, just clicking sound and sometimes lighting comes back on for a seconds (as you can see in the video), central locking doesn't work - again, just more clicking sound from the doors. Generally, anything that is electric doesn't work, just makes clicking sounds.

So, I checked my battery, and it is at 12.6V, which is perfect. I checked if car's body has ground on it - yes, it does. Then I disconnected the battery and waited for a couple of minutes and reconnected it again. After this my car works like a charm, without any issues what so ever. Alternator is charging at 14.3V constantly.

What could be the issue? My guess is most probably the wires that are connecting battery to the car. I would say that my starter is going bad, but it works beautifully without any noises and also, all of my electronics didn't work...

I has this issue about a week ago. And I cured it by disconnecting the battery and reconnecting it again (after a few minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be in the question. A full check on the battery clamps and cables, including the earth attachment to the vehicle should be carried out. Dont forget that the battery cables themselves can break down internally even when they look OK externally. The clicking and lights going haywire you descibe point to a battery, battery circuits or starter problem.

Comment: I cleaned all the connections as much as I could, but points where wires are pressed to connection clams for battery seem to be very oxidised. Most probably my problem is located there. To be on the safe side, I connected new ground wire from my battery to the body of the car.

Thank you for your tips!

Answer (score 0):

This one nearly screams "battery connection". I think you need to clean those battery posts & clamps with a battery brush.